# Activities with or Without Contacts

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I want to pull this report - Activities with or without contacts where i can show activities and the related contact details(if contact is mapped in the activity).

I tried using the standard "Tasks and Events" report type provided by sfdc but in it custom contact fields are not available for reporting.

The second i tried was using custom report type but was not able to relate to contact.

Hope you understand the problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Angad

Answer (score 2):

It's all already there ;) Create new report and use "Activities with Contacts" report type.

[image]